# Is it possible to automatically generate descriptors from a data set for use with ANN?

Tags: java, python, neural-network

I would like to classify a dataset automatically into several classes. Is it possible to train a neural net without coding any descriptors?

I am classifying a set of fixed size Pictures. I do not really want to write a set of descriptors for them, though. Is there a way where I can classify my set with little effort?

I have a large dataset and only 7-8 classes in which to classify.

I would be extremely happy if I could snag some sample code along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very broad class of neural networks. For what you're doing, you will want to look for one based on [unsupervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning).  Typically, these are based on [Hebb's rule](http://urrg.eng.usm.my/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=194%3aunsupervised-neural-network-hebbian-learning-&catid=31%3aarticles&Itemid=70).

For your case, you might find [competitive learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_learning) to be suitable. Essentially, you set an output neuron for each class (so the 7-8 you're expecting), and strengthen the weights to the most active for a given input pattern. This results in clustering; input patterns that are similar activate the same output neuron, strengthening those connections and causing the neurons to specialize for the different classes.